# CacheManager.net (Redis) - Cache.Add only supports hashes?

Tags: caching, stackexchange.redis, cachemanager

I've just begun playing around with CacheManager.Net to add distributed caching capabilities to our app. My level 2 cache is Redis and it seem to work fine.

I notice that when I do a Cache.Add(cacheItem), it always gets added as a Hash to redis.  Using CacheManager, is it possible to add objects as other redis data types? Say as a "String"?

Thanks.
U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's currently not supported. CacheManager stores meta data with the cached item to implement other things and all that is stored within one hash.
The operation is implemented with lua scripts and is pretty fast, there is almost no overhead vs just storing a string.
If you have specific use cases which can be applied to other cache vendors, too (not only redis) feel free to post a feature request on github